# Asynchronous messaging with AMQP, Kombu, and gevent

Tags: python, asynchronous, amqp, gevent, kombu

I am trying to crate asynchronous kombu consumer using gevents in python. I watched this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nGiBdcIQiMQ which should be it, but it is not complete, those guys did not show what they promised on the beginning. I also found this example https://github.com/agoragames/haigha/blob/master/examples/gevent_hello.py which works great for me but I need to implement it using Kombu.
Does someone have an experience in combining Kombu and gevent. Any working hello world example would be great. By the way I am using RabbitMQ as MQ.